# UINavigationBar Font properties only seems to adjust title but not breacrumbs portion of view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I used the following in my AppDelegate.m to change the font properties of my UINavigationBar:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           [UIColor darkBlue], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                           [UIFont fontWithName:SYSTEM_FONT_TYPE size:SYSTEM_FONT_SIZE*1.2], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
```

However, this seems to adjust only the title-displaying font and not the breadcrumb back-tracing portion:

[image: menu image]

Looking over the class reference, I must be missing it because I don't see anything else to reference as a property or method other than those relating to TitleTextAttributes. What else should I change to change the left text's font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *backbutton =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];    

[backbutton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor darkBlue],UITextAttributeTextColor,[UIFont fontWithName:TEXTFONT size:16.0f],UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

or alternatively,

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor darkBlue],[UIFont fontWithName:TEXTFONT size:16.0f],UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't seem to work. The only way I can get the command to run without an error is with the following:   [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor darkBlue],[UIFont fontWithName:SYSTEM_FONT_TYPE size:SYSTEM_FONT_SIZE*.7], nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; but this has no effect. If I use your form of the command or substitute NSFontAttributeName for UI... I get a runtime error

Comment: continued: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]: second object of each pair must be non-nil.  Or, did you forget to nil-terminate your parameter list?'
*** First throw call stack: